# Getting network traffic asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c, asp.net-mvc

So i was searching for ways on how to get network traffic speed on your nic and here on the forum i have found some ways by using bytesreceived. altough if you have to measure it by second and which means I have to use a timer or stopwatch. 
It will give performance issues and maybe mem leaks. any other ways to avoid this?

Further more speed is not the most important , what I want is total amount of data downloaded and uploaded (seperate). I was thiking to count it up when I would measure speed -> any other ways to count , measure traffic data?

Comment: Sounds more like a job for [existing tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=network+traffic+inspection+tools) purposely built instead of reinventing the wheel. Additionally, if you're really into networking ops, then similar tools exist in network management hardware.

Comment: @edsf and what kinda external tools. i want to put network data on my dashboard but i'm also going to capture network traffic with wireshark . can I use wireshark tools for getting network speed too?